# How to retrieve data from Firebase that have 2 layer structure?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have 2 layer structure of table inside my Firebase. I have problem with retrieving this. How can I retrieve this data from my Firebase? I have provided my main code and my Order class.

[image]

here is my code

```
 databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Order");
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    orderList = new ArrayList<>();

                        for (DataSnapshot orderSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                            orderList.add(orderSnapshot.getValue(Order.class));
                        }

                    psOrderAdapter PsOrderAdapter = new psOrderAdapter(orderList);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(PsOrderAdapter);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(ManageOrder.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

```
public class Order {
    public String cust_id;
    public String pro_id;
    public String total;
    public String name;
    public String address;
    public String phone;
    public String status;
    public String date;
    public String dateTime;


    public Order() {
    }

    public Order(String cust_id, String pro_id, String total, String name, String address, String phone, String status,String date, String dateTime) {
        this.cust_id = cust_id;
        this.total = total;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.pro_id = pro_id;
        this.status = status;
        this.date=date;
        this.dateTime=dateTime;
    }
//getter and setter
}
```

I'm expecting a result a result like this

[image]

Comment: What are u getting now?

Comment: Can you post your Order.class ?

Comment: @PeterHaddad I got a blank page since i cant access the id

Comment: @GastónSaillén I have posted my `Order` class

Comment: What is your actual requirements? one user one product?

Comment: my requirement is one user can purchase many product. I want to create a view page for admin where admin can view how many order that the admin has received. the admin also can view the details of that particular customer products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
for(DataSnapshot orderSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    for(DataSnapshot ds : orderSnapshot.getChildren()) {
         orderList.add(ds.getValue(Order.class));
    } 
}
```

Add another for loop to be able to retrieve the data.

Comment: thank you it worked. But I noticed that if the customer have more than 1 product id under the same customer id. The list get duplicate. What i mean here is the same customer id get duplicated

Comment: The code in the answer will retrieve the data that is in your database. In your database you have same customer ID with different product ID, so it will retrieve that..

Comment: how to make sure that it will only display one Customer Id only.  What I mean is how to make sure that the same Id won't get repeated/showed in my view page?

Comment: U are using a recyclerview right? If u dnt want the customerid to be in each `item` then remove it from the array and just add the product name and ID, on click of each item retrieve product details

Comment: thank you! I've been stuck with this for 5 days thank you for enlighten me up!